# Inherit from an instance of template class

Tags: c++

Simple question here. I have to define classes that will contain sets of books, movies, CDs. I defined a template class, say `Set<T>`, with all the common methods, and then defined classes that derive from a particular instance (is it the correct term?) of the `Set` class

```
class Movies_set : public Set<Movie>
{
    /* ... */
}
```

in which I define some other methods (say a function to search for actors). Is it a good programming technique or are there more convenient methods?

Comment: What is the functional difference between a `Movies_set` and a `Set<Movie>`?

Comment: For example, a Movies_set could have a method to search for an actor, while the generic Set as just a method to search in the title (all the classes Movie, Book, Album have a `search_in_title` method)

Comment: That seems a bit off. If `Set<Movie>` doesn't already have specialised behaviour for a `Movie`, then the sort-of-duplicate-named `Movies_set` should not either. I'd expect the two types to be equivalent, if not identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what Set actually is. I suspect Set is something similar to std::set and in that case, I would advice against derivation and steer you towards composition.

The reason deriving from Set is a bad idea is because it exposes the API of set, which has nothing to do whatsoever with MovieSet. If you need methods to make searches to your MovieSet object, implement them on MovieSet itself, especially since, as you pointed out, you are going to augment MovieSet's interface.

This way, you would also gain something very powerful : encapsulation. If for some reason you decide to change from a Set to a std::map, the interface of your base class is likely to change and any code that accesses MovieSet will be impacted. If you had stored Set as a private data member, you would not run into this issue, as you would have already defined MovieSet's appropriate accessors.

That of course, if all based on my premise that Set is actually just a container.

Comment: +1 for mentioning composition as an alternative of subclassing

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I used this method because the classes Movie_set, Books_set and Album_set have lots of methods in common, like `Add`, `Remove`, `search_in_title`, so I thought it would be faster to implement them in the same template class.

Comment: I suggest then that you have a common base class for Movie_set, Book_set and Album_set, let's say Media_set, that knows how to search for these similar object types.

Additionally, it seems you would need a class named Media that is the base class for Movie, Book and Album, if that's not already the case.

Comment: I have the class Media of course. So I create the class Media_set that has a Set class (I have to implement the set class, can't use std classes) as a field?

Comment: Well, that's what *I* would do, given my understanding of your problem.

I am curious as to why you can't use std::set tough. It's unfortunate. :(

Comment: This is a project for a basic C++ object oriented programming course, so I have some specifications to follow, including the existence of a different class for each set of Media, and the fact that I have to implement my own set class with basic functions such as add, remove, find.

Comment: @Pincopallino : That seems reasonable. Just make sure to make it log(n) ;)

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. Say that `Media` has a function `Print()` to print formatted output on the console and its derivates `Book` redefine this function. If I make the Media_set class that stores objects of the base type `Media`, then the function called is the one of the base class and not of its derivates. (I don't know if I made myself clear, my English is quite bad)

Comment: Media::Print should be pure virtual, then implement the method in derived classes. Then calling mediaPtr->Print() will end up calling the right version of print.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely nothing wrong with doing this, and it's quite a common idiom.  That said, you might want to make sure that a `typedef` is sufficient enough.  If your `Movies_set` adds no new specific functionality, it's probably better to:

```
typedef Set<Movie> Movies_Set;
```

Obviously, if Movies_set introduces specific functionality pertinent to movies, the inheritance is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely fine.

In fact, there is a well-known pattern which does almost similar thing, except that it uses the derived class itself as the type argument to the base class template:

- [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: I do not think this is that, he is not passing the base into the generic, he is passing a third type to the base. and aliasing the combination as a new child type.

Comment: @111111: Correct. I overlooked that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

if Movie_set doesn't add any over the implementation of Set then it is a waste of time deriving from Set

you are better of typedefing it.

```
typedef Set<Movie> movie_set;
```

like that. However if you are specializing the Set further with new member functions and data members then the is ok, although deriving from containers ins't common (usually you own them). but Also long as the necessary function are virtual (destructor) it should be ok.